# Login in Oracle vm manager using python

Tags: python, virtual-machine

I am working on a task where I need to access oracle vm manager using python, get logged in and download some data. How it is possible to access oracle vm manager using python ie make connection using username password, & access data.

Answer (score 0):

I would look in to the REST API. See the documentation, here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50245_01/E50253/html/vmapi-rest.html